# Using RtMIDI, MIDISendSysex sends no events to virtual ports

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, midi

just started using RtMIDI in Xcode to prototype up some MIDI stuff. It's working fine but hit a stumbling block.

Using the example midiout.cpp without modifying anything:

- If I send MIDI events to an already existing MIDI port, all events are sent ok.
- If I send MIDI events to a created virtual port, all events *except* sysex events are sent.

Having a look in the library code, all MIDI events except sysex are sent (on OSX) using the os call MIDIReceived. Sysex events are sent using MIDISendSysex. This is as it should be.

Now, no errors are thrown, everything is being executed as it should, the MIDISendSysex call is not failing - just that no sysex events arrive at the destination. They just disappear into a black hole!

Anybody else come across this or have any help, suggestions, workarounds?

Thanks,

(Xcode 4.6.2, OSX 10.9.1, using MIDIMonitor & MIDIPipe to monitor the traffic on MIDI ports, both show same results of sysex events not arriving on virtual ports from midiout.cpp)

Ok, here's the sendMessage routing that's doing the actual sending:

```
    void MidiOutCore :: sendMessage( std::vector *message )
    {
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // We use the MIDISendSysex() function to asynchronously send sysex
      // messages.  Otherwise, we use a single CoreMidi MIDIPacket.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // error handling code removed for brevity

      MIDITimeStamp timeStamp = AudioGetCurrentHostTime();
      CoreMidiData *data = static_cast (apiData_);
      OSStatus result;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // IF EVENT IS SYSEX
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

      if ( message->at(0) == 0xF0 ) {               // sysex start byte
        while ( sysexBuffer != 0 ) usleep( 1000 );  // sleep 1 ms

       sysexBuffer = new char[nBytes];

       // Copy data to buffer.
       for ( unsigned int i=0; iat(i);

       // build sysex request
       data->sysexreq.destination = data->destinationId;        // destinaiondId is valid endpointref
       data->sysexreq.data = (Byte *)sysexBuffer;
       data->sysexreq.bytesToSend = nBytes;
       data->sysexreq.complete = 0;
       data->sysexreq.completionProc = sysexCompletionProc;
       data->sysexreq.completionRefCon = &(data->sysexreq);

       // send the data
       // this works when we are connected to a 'real' MIDI port/device, but fails on a virtual port
       // destinationId is an endpointref and valid and id is good
       // tried to use data->endpoint (also an endpointref with id) but doesn't send either
       result = MIDISendSysex( &(data->sysexreq) );
       return;
      }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // IF EVENT IS NOT SYSEX
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

      MIDIPacketList packetList;
      MIDIPacket *packet = MIDIPacketListInit( &packetList );
      packet = MIDIPacketListAdd( &packetList, sizeof(packetList), packet, timeStamp, nBytes, (const Byte *) &message->at( 0 ) );

      // Send to any destinations that may have connected to us.
      // this sends to virtual MIDI ports
      if ( data->endpoint ) {
        result = MIDIReceived( data->endpoint, &packetList );
        if ( result != noErr ) {
          errorString_ = "MidiOutCore::sendMessage: error sending MIDI to virtual destinations.";
          RtMidi::error( RtError::WARNING, errorString_ );
        }
      }

      // And send to an explicit destination port if we're connected.
      // this sends to regular real MIDI devices we are connected to, not virtual ports
      if ( connected_ ) {
        result = MIDISend( data->port, data->destinationId, &packetList );
        if ( result != noErr ) {
          errorString_ = "MidiOutCore::sendMessage: error sending MIDI message to port.";
          RtMidi::error( RtError::WARNING, errorString_ );
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Please show us the example code.

Comment: Hi - this is using the midiout.cpp file that comes with the library. I'm not sure how much I should post? The example program just lets the user choose an existing port, or creating a virtual port, and fires some example MIDI events to each. Will put the link up to rtmidi in a sec...

Comment: rtmidi is here: http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/ with the download: http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/release/rtmidi-2.0.1.tar.gz. As I say, I was having problems with my code so I went back and checked the behaviour with the example program that comes with the library, and this shows the same behaviour.

Comment: midiout.cpp: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4211158/code/midiout.cpp

RtMidi.cpp: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4211158/code/RtMidi.cpp

RtMidi.h: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4211158/code/RtMidi.h

RtError.h: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4211158/code/RtError.h

Comment: Interestingly - the non-sysex events are sent in two ways -if connected to an existing port, rtmidi uses MIDISend, but if there is an endpoint (virtual port) is also sends to this as well using MIDIReceived. 

If I comment out the MIDIReceived sender, then regular events don't show up on a virtual port either. So, this seems related to MIDISendSysex not showing up on a virtual port - it seems like it only wants to send to a regular MIDI port and not a virtual one. Investigating...

Comment: I admit I have no idea of MIDI stuff, not even XCode. But the best way to get answers here ist to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with *your own* code.

Comment: Indeed, but my own code is not the problem, it's the rtmidi library code or it's behaviour (which I've linked to if anyone wants to take a look as it's rather too much to post), but you're right, I think maybe this is the wrong place to get help on this particular issue...

Comment: I think I will contact the library author for some clarification into the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow up note - this was a bug in RTMidi which should be fixed in the next version. It's related to the fact that in CoreMIDI, the MIDISendSysex() call does not send to virtual ports, it will work on real ports only.

I have updated my local copy of RTMIDI to handle sysex events using MIDIReceived() as recommended by this thread on the CoreAdio mailing list: 
http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2006/Jan/msg00236.html

It now sends sysex to virtual ports and behaves as expected.

Comment: actually not 100% true. Sysex can be transmitted thru virtual ports. The receiver needs to be compliant to the sysex rules. So the header needs to be correctly set. Knowing this because a couple of months ago i made a virtual midi port plugin that received sysex and send back if needed to transmit song text characters. 
When you used ableton to test, consider the DAW you used can in some circumstances not send sysex out of the box. And yes on virtual ports the sender and receiver is turned around. So MIDISendSysex is useless in this case, MIDIReceived() is the way to go.. correct!

Comment: This is still an issue 7 years later! Using Linux.